# Making a new line

Tags: python-3.x

```
def formatter(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    print "%r, %r, %r, %r" %(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

formatter(1, 2, 3, 4)
formatter("one",\n "two",\n "three",\n "four")
```

I know that it's can be add th\n among the def instead,
But I wish to add \n inside one of the variables, so another wont be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def formatter(*args): #Use the star operator
    for a in args:
        print(a, end="")

formatter("stuff\n", "things", "other", "Stuff\n")
```

Use the star operator, it enables you to use variadic arguments.

Comment: @LeonG are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: @LeonG because if you are using 2, you can't really do what you want to.. Or you could use the `future` module or whatever it's called. I would check the documentation.

Comment: I'm using python 3. I did wrote the same exactly how you wrote but it's not working :(

Comment: Yes! thanks you! I just erased the ( end="") and it works, I don't understand what's the  (end="") function for.

Comment: Now I realize I was using python 2.X.. so sorry, but may I know something similar end="" in python 2.x?